# How to find what process won't die?

Tags: process

I'm having an intermittent issue where Emacs appears to freeze. Pressing `C-g` eventually returns control of Emacs to me with the following message in the `*Messages*` buffer:

`Waiting for process to die...done`

How do I find out what process is hogging Emacs?

Comment: Hard to say, but the first thing might be to investigate the return value of `(process-list)`. That won't help much if the process is gone before you get to evaluate this function, though.

Comment: On what operating system? If Emacs is frozen, external debugging tools will probably help.

Answer (score 4):

You might try at the command line:

kill -USR2 pid

where pid is the emacs process that is stuck. Sometimes this leads to a traceback that might tell you what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never.. :)

I found that xclip was causing the hang in my case.. I ran pstree both during the hang and after, to notice the difference in the child processes of the emacs process. hth